# Looking for a story board alike sheet for a custom rpg

Tags: tools, house-rules, dice, online-roleplaying

I am playing via Skype to a custom role playing game with some friends. The game is like an Age of Empires by turns and no one but the GM knows about anyone. I don't know the rules (dice based) but that doesn't matter to the question.

The thing is I would like to track down my movements and my actions, to be able to see my progress through the game each week.

We started with 30 people and no restrictions. So we ask to the GM things to do or the week and after the week he report us the results of our actions. We usually spread in groups our people and sometimes we are not aware of their actions until they came back to us after they finish their duty if we sent away from us.

So the thing is on a regular day things could go like this:

- 1 arquitect
- 1 chef
- 1 blacksmith
- ....

  1. Day 1:
- 6 guys working on the forge -> 2 days.
- Blacksmith making shields and poles -> 10 days...
- 1 guy on the fields -> 14 days (whole turn)

  1. Day 3:
- Those 6 guys from the forge now will work on something else...
- ....

So that's kind of a turn. And I need a tool that makes the availability of my workers easier and clarify what I am doing during each turns. Now I am using this [Google Docs tool](https://www.smartsheet.com/) but it is not intended for this and I am encountering some problems making it work for my game. So any one has an idea about what can I do to organize myself or a better tool that will ease my life?

Thanks in advance. Sorry for the *tl;dr;* and if you need any additional info just ask in the comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use a simple spreadsheet? Here's a quick example of a dozen people organized for 14 days:

[image: Sample schedule]

You could further color-code it or customize it to fit your needs. If I'm missing some key need, let me know in comments.

Comment: Thanks @Dan but I think I didn't explained as I want. The thing is I have people, not professionals, one day I could have the chef doing cooking stuff and the day after on an expedition to gather minerals because some other person died.
I also would like to track events, due to the nature of the game. For example, yesterday I was attacked and I lost 3 peasants and 3 Yaks. Other thing I would like to track are states for tasks. Definitely a spreadsheet is a good option but I just wanted to know if someone here could provide a better option. If that's not the case I'll check your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidDiez you can still use a spreadsheet, just not this one. You can have a column to track each of your professionals, and then a column for events. On the first rows, put the starting stats, and then add or subtract on following rows. In the final row, you can have tha current status. So for say, on the first line you can have (3;2 Initial) meaning 3 blacksmiths and 2 peasants. Next, you can have (-2;-1; raided by turks) meaning that you lost that people in this raid. The last row can have a SUM, so it will read (1;1; current) You can also track time, with a bit of tweaking.